# how to subsort of LEFT JOIN in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

How can I build a query to sort the results by vl_name (vldescription) alphabetically, and subsort table vllinks by vlk_addeddate from the latest with internal limit equal to 1?

```
SELECT 
aa.vl_id, aa.vl_name, aa.vl_code, aa.vl_vcc, aa.vl_description, 
bb.vlk_id, bb.vlk_vlid, bb.vlk_link, bb.vlk_platform, bb.vlk_location, bb.vlk_addeddate, 
le.vop_vlid, le.vop_thumbnail, 
cx.vcc_id, cx.vcc_type, cx.vcc_brand, cx.vcc_variant 

FROM vldescription AS aa 
LEFT JOIN vllinks AS bb ON aa.vl_id = bb.vlk_vlid 
LEFT JOIN vlofferphotos AS le ON le.vop_vlid = aa.vl_id 
LEFT JOIN vlcarcats AS cx ON cx.vcc_id = aa.vl_vcc 

WHERE aa.vl_vcc = '$change_me_if_you_need' 
GROUP BY vl_id 
ORDER BY vl_name
```

Table vlcarcats (vcc_

```
vcc_id  |   vcc_type    |   vcc_brand   |   vcc_variant 
1       |   OpenPlace   |   SomeCorp1   |   website
2       |   ForPrive    |   SomeCorp2   |   other way
```

Table vldescription

```
vl_id   |   vl_name |   vl_code |   vl_vcc  |   vl_description
1       |   OpTECC  |   xDAOcm  |   1023    |   text, text,...
2       |   NewCop  |   d9MMo2  |   42      |   more text,...
```

Table vllinks (vlk_vlid == vl_id)

```
vlk_id  |   vlk_vlid    |   vlk_link    |   vlk_platform    |   vlk_location    |   vlk_addeddate
1       |   1           |   http://...  |   1               |   USA             |   2014-01-10
2       |   2           |   http://...  |   1               |   UK              |   2014-01-12
3       |   2           |   ftp://...   |   2               |   UK              |   2014-01-15
4       |   2           |   ftp://...   |   2               |   India           |   2014-01-19
5       |   1           |   ftp://...   |   2               |   Austria         |   2014-01-22
```

Table vlofferphotos (vop_vlid == vl_id)

```
vop_vlid    |   vop_thumbnail
1           |   abcdefg.jpg
2           |   hijklmn.jpg
```

Comment: What does this mean: "with internal limit equal to 1"?

Comment: please add desired output, it's hard to guess what you actually want.